# Impact on assigning value for variable with and without 'this' in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

```
function Myfunc()
{
    this.a = 10;
    a = 20;
    alert(this.a);
    alert(a);
}


Myfunc();
```

O/P: 20,20

What is the differnce bw `this.a = 10;` and `a = 20;` in the above code?

Comment: [`"use strict"` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to get two exceptions. Your code uses bad practices.